# How do I enable the Google Classroom APIs for my testing & development GSuite Organization?

Tags: google-classroom

It's pretty much all in the title, but I'd like to develop against the GSuite for Education APIs.  Unfortunately, the approvals process rejected me specifically because I'm not an educational institution.  This is despite me indicating that I'm a business looking to develop an application targeting the education APIs...

I go to [this URI](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access), but it doesn't give me anything helpful:

[image: Snapshot of Page]

Given that none of those options result in me getting a test domain, how am I supposed to develop against these APIs without a test instance to mock data with?

Answer (score 1):

As far as testing goes, here's what worked for me.

1. Went to the [Sign-In page for Classroom](https://edu.google.com/products/productivity-tools/classroom/index.html).
2. Created a classroom. Encountered a prompt, ticked it and continued. Classroom created. Then, I invited a test email as student.
3. Went to the Javascript [Classroom API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/js), copied the code and ran it.
4. It works. Up to you to explore Classroom API methods further.

[image]

Comment: I get told that I can't use classroom with the account.  The question here is how to enable classroom for my domain as a developer.

Comment: why not try to expand the quickstart and provide your own interface for CREATE UPDATE DELETE Classroom methods, etc. It'll look like full-blown website.

Comment: @Omega, you already know you have to be a registered school to enable it on your domain. So this is the workaround where you can play with it.

Comment: I tried it with a personal account, and was able to create a class. I'm having trouble adding students, but that's probably not related....